# Can I store an HDF5 subgroup in a variable and access it later after the HDF5 file was closed?

Tags: python-3.x, h5py

I have an hdf5 file with several subgroups. One subgroup has multiple datasets. I wish to extract one subgroup with its multiple datasets inside.
How do I store this one subgroup in a variable, close the hdf5 file, and access it later, please?
Is this even possible, please?

Edit: Thank you. For the dict-option I suggest:

```
data={}
with h5py.File('path to file',"r") as f:
    sub_group='/entry/path/sg/'    
    for key in f[sub_group].keys():
        print(key)
        path_dataset=f[sub_group][key].name
        data[key]=f[path_dataset][:]
```

Comment: Make a python `dict` and download the datasets as arrays to  it.  A h5py group is supposed behave a lot like a dict.

Comment: After you close the HDF5 file, you can't access any of the objects in the file (groups or datasets). As noted above, you can read each dataset into a NumPy array (before closing), then reference the appropriate array as needed. Managing Group/Dataset hierarchy depends on the complexity. Be careful with a dictionary if you have a lot of large datasets and limited memory.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you maybe show a good code example how you would do this? I think the dict option seems the way forward at the moment, otherwise I have around 25 Numpy arrays and have to drag them along.